# Matrix to data frame with row/columns numbers

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a 10x10 matrix in R, called `run_off`. I would like to convert this matrix to a data frame that contains the entries of the matrix (the order doesn't really matter, although I'd prefer it to be filled by row) as well as the row and columns numbers of the entries as separate columns in the data frame, so that for instance element `run_off[2,3]` has a row in the data frame with 3 columns, the first containing the element itself, the second containing 2 and the third containing 3.

This is what I have so far:

```
run_off <- matrix(data = c(45630, 23350, 2924, 1798, 2007, 1204, 1298, 563, 777, 621,
                           53025, 26466, 2829, 1748, 732, 1424, 399, 537, 340, NA,
                           67318, 42333, -1854, 3178, 3045, 3281, 2909, 2613, NA, NA,
                           93489, 37473, 7431, 6648, 4207, 5762, 1890, NA, NA, NA,
                           80517, 33061, 6863, 4328, 4003, 2350, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                           68690, 33931, 5645, 6178, 3479, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                           63091, 32198, 8938, 6879, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           64430, 32491, 8414, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                           68548, 35366, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                           76013, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
                    , nrow = 10, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)

df <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(run_off)) {
  for (k in 1:ncol(run_off)) {
    claim <- run_off[i,k]
    acc_year <- i
    dev_year <- k
    df[???, "claims"] <- claim # Problem here
    df[???, "acc_year"] <- acc_year # and here
    df[???, "dev_year"] <- dev_year # and here


  }
}
```

`dev_year` refers to the column number of the matrix entry and `acc_year`to the row number. My problem is that I don't know the proper index to use for the data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are not interested in the NA elements? You can use `which` and the `arr.ind = TRUE` argument to return a two column matrix of array indices for each value and `cbind` this to the values, excluding the `NA` values:

```
#  Get array indices
ind <- which( ! is.na(run_off) , arr.ind = TRUE ) 

#  cbind indices to values
out <- cbind( run_off[ ! is.na( run_off ) ] , ind )

head( as.data.frame( out ) )
#     V1 row col
#1 45630   1   1
#2 53025   2   1
#3 67318   3   1
#4 93489   4   1
#5 80517   5   1
#6 68690   6   1
```

Use `t()` on the matrix first if you want to fill by row, e.g. `which( ! is.na( t( run_off ) ) , arr.ind = TRUE )` (and when you cbind it).